# Best way to write an async method in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I have a service object that simply executes queries against an EF Core repository on top of a Microsoft SQL Database. I am trying to convert these synchronous methods to **async** versions. Here's an example of one simplified method ...

**Synchronous Version**

```
public List<Contact> GetContacts()
{
    var ret = this.dbContext.Contacts.ToList(); 
    return ret;
}
```

I have seen several way to NOT create ASYNC methods ... then again ... I've seen a couple different ways on how you SHOULD create async methods. I am caught between which of the two methods below is considered the "right" or "best" way to create an async methods.

**Async Version 1**

```
public Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(this.dbContext.Contacts.ToList());
}
```

OR

**Async Version 2**

```
public async Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
{
    List<Contact> ret = null;

    await Task.Run(()=>{
        ret = this.dbContext.Contacts.ToList(); 
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Potentially complicating this further is, if the query contains several lines of logic.

Here is the same method with more of the detail included. If you see issues aside from the async topic, then I would love to hear about them in a PM or something, but for this thread I want to focus on the await/async stuff.

**Complete Synchronous Code**

```
public PaginationResult<Contact> GetContacts(PaginationSpec pagingSpec, List<Expression<Func<Models.Contact, bool>>> filter = null)
{
    IQueryable<Contact> query = ContactService.GetContactQuery(this.ctx);

    if (filter != null && filter.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in filter)
        {
            query = query.Where(item);
        }
    }

    // get the record count
    //
    var recordcount = query.Count();

    // get the pagination
    //
    var stage = pagingSpec.ApplyPagination<Models.Contact>(query);

    // Construct the paged result.
    // 
    var ret = new PaginationResult<Models.Contact>(recordcount, pagingSpec.CurrentPage, pagingSpec.PageSize, stage.ToList());

    return ret;
}
```

How would I wrap this in the appropriate syntax to make this method asynchronous? I can think of a couple of ways ...

**Async Version 1**

```
public Task<PaginationResult<Contact>> GetContactsAsync(PaginationSpec pagingSpec, List<Expression<Func<Models.Contact, bool>>> filter = null)
{
    return Task.FromResult(GetContacts(pagingSpec, filter)) // simply call the synchronous method ??;
}
```

OR

**Async Version 2**

```
public async Task<PaginationResult<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
{
    PaginationResult<Contact> ret = null;

    await Task.Run(()=>{
    
        // Encapsulate the execution code within the RUN method ??
        //
        IQueryable<Contact> query = ContactService.GetContactQuery(this.ctx);

        if (filter != null && filter.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in filter)
            {
                query = query.Where(item);
            }
        }

        // get the record count
        //
        var recordcount = query.Count();

        // Apply the pagination spec to the query
        //
        var stage = pagingSpec.ApplyPagination<Models.Contact>(query);

        // Construct the esult.
        // 
        ret = new PaginationResult<Models.Contact>(recordcount, pagingSpec.CurrentPage, pagingSpec.PageSize, stage.ToList());
        });

    return ret;
}
```

Are either of these NOT appropriate, BETTER than one or the other or am I missing a 3rd option?

Trying to learn this await/async stuff and any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You have 2 separate questions here and maybe multiple variations of them. anyway don't pretend to be async when you are not. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html if there are async versions of a method use them, don't wrap them in a task (even though you haven't shown that, however just putting that out there).

Comment: Maybe, you are not quite at the stage of asking a question yet, check out Stephen Clearys blogs, he is one of the most well read authors on tasks and async and await and often answers questions here (1000s of them)

Comment: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) Spoiler alert, the answer is no. Btw what are you trying to achieve by enhancing the API of your service with async methods? Do you want to improve the scalability of the service? Do you want to improve the responsiveness of the clients that use the service? Something else?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I guess the thought was that there may be an instance where the service methods may be called but not block execution of subsequent commands. That was my understanding of what async/await was all about. If I have properly understood the posts that have been referenced however, THAT responsibility is not up to the SERVICE but up to how the CONSUMER chooses to consume the method(?) So instead I would add to my APPLICATION code ... `await Task.Run(()=>ContactSvcInstance.GetContacts())` ... instead??

Comment: Yeap, exactly. That's what the experts recommend. Your service shouldn't expose asynchronous methods, unless they are truly asynchronous, deep in their core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of those are generally considered incorrect.

> Async Version 1

The problem with this one is that it is not actually asynchronous. It's just doing the same synchronous work and wrapping it in a `Task<T>`.

> Async Version 2

The problem with this one is that it is asynchronous from the perspective of the caller, but synchronous in its implementation. It's just using `Task.Run` to run synchronous code on a thread pool thread so it *appears* asynchronous. This is what I call "fake asynchronous", which is OK (not ideal) for desktop apps, and certainly not recommended for ASP.NET apps.

A more proper solution would look like this:

```
public async Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync()
{
    return await this.dbContext.Contacts.ToListAsync();
}
```

This is assuming you have a `ToListAsync` method available. Note the similarity to the synchronous version:

```
public List<Contact> GetContacts()
{
    return this.dbContext.Contacts.ToList(); 
}
```

Generally speaking, you want to start at the *lowest* level, i.e., the code that actually executes the `IQueryable`. In this case, I'm assuming that's `ToList`, but if `ToList` is your own method, then it might be whatever that method calls. Once you find the lowest-level code, then change *that* to use `await`, and let the async grow from there.

Comment: I noticed the ToListAsync() method after posting this and was curious if I should be using that in order to create "async" versions instead of the Run() or FromResult() methods. You answered that question before I asked! Thanks!

Comment: Everybody is just saying what not to do and use .NET Framework async methods. But what if I want to implement my own async method from scratch. How to do it properly.

Comment: @Rahul: Use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.